# Codeigniter -- ability to pass login credentials in URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter application that requires users to log in, and their username and password is checked for a match in a MySQL database. If it matches I let them in. Pretty simple, nothing terribly secure.

I'm still new to logging in and sessions and all that, but I was wondering how I might, at times, generate a special link that will temporarily allow a user direct access into the logged in part of the site without requiring them to enter a username and password. Is there a simple solution for this? Since this is still just somewhat of a prototype/demo, I'm more interested in reliability and simplicity than security. Thanks.

Comment: 1. For specific user lets say test_user you can generate token(long random string), set timeout for it, and save it to DB linked to that customer. 2. While using url that contains that token, check it, login him as customer test_user programatically, 3. Invalidate token.

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/otphp - time one time password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a special link where you will create a function which is called your login function passing username and password by hard coded which username and password has to your database and create a button in login page where user click that button with this special link that will temporarily allow a user direct access into the logged in part of the site without requiring them to enter a username and password.

Below is sample code:

```
special link www.test.com/admin/auth/special_login

 function special_login()
  {
    $this->index("username","password");
  }

 funciton index (username =false, password =false)
  {
   //your regular loging macanisam wehre just you chech if any value in parameters then you will log in with this username and password otherwise you will be pass by your regular post data
  }
```